# Mocking WebSecurity provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nunit, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to create some simple unit tests for my controllers and I've come across an issue.

I'm using the new membership provider in MVC 4 and getting the `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` and storing that value in the database.

When I run my unit tests against this it's failing and I think I have track this back to the fact that the `WebSecurity` isn't being mocked at all.

Here's my code if it helps at all,

The Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateOrganisationViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Group group = _groupService.Create(
                new Group
                {
                    Name = viewModel.Name,
                    Slug = viewModel.Name.ToSlug(),
                    Profile = new Profile
                    {
                        Country = viewModel.SelectedCountry,
                        Description = viewModel.Description
                    },
                    CreatedById = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId,
                    WhenCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    Administrators = new List<User> {_userService.SelectById(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)}
                });
            RedirectToAction("Index", new {id = group.Slug});
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The Test

```
    [Test]
    public void SuccessfulCreatePost()
    {
        CreateOrganisationViewModel createOrganisationViewModel = new CreateOrganisationViewModel
        {
            Description = "My Group, bla bla bla",
            Name = "My Group",
            SelectedCountry = "gb"
        };

        IUserService userService = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IUserService>();
        IGroupService groupService = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IGroupService>();
        groupService.Stub(gS => gS.Create(null)).Return(new Group {Id = 1});
        GroupController controller = new GroupController(groupService, userService);
        RedirectResult result = controller.Create(createOrganisationViewModel) as RedirectResult;
        Assert.AreEqual("Index/my-group", result.Url);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is to create a wrapper class around WebSecurity - say `WebSecurityWrapper`. Expose the static WebSecurity methods such as `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` as instance methods on the wrapper. The wrapper's job in this case would be simply to delegate all the calls to `WebSecurity`.

Inject `WebSecurityWrapper` into the `GroupController`'s constructor. Now, you can stub the wrapper using the mocking framework of your choice - and thus test the controller logic.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used what you said but took it further and interfaced it all out.  Thanks for the help